# Bot initiating chat in Messenger *Group*

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a Messenger group for a recreational sports team (6 members), our schedule changes from week to week and we have to check a web site, which get tedious. I want to write a bot which writes a short message to our Messenger group once a week to announce our game times. There is no interaction from the group members. I want the message to be automatic (initiated by the bot), not triggered by an interaction from our group.

Is this possible with Messenger API? Everything I can find on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/ seems to suggest only two options:

- One-on-one bot, where the bot can asynchronously write a message to the user.
- Group "Chat Extensions", where a group member has to manually trigger a bot action (webview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, those are the only options. Currently, bots are not supported in group chats.